# How to reduce the build time when a UWP project includes a lot of content files

Tags: performance, deployment, build, uwp, compilation

I am developing a UWP project in C# using VS2017. I now have a requirement to add approximately 5000 image files (jpg & png) into the build so that they are included within the .appx bundle for eventual deployment.

So I have added the files to the project within a folder structure and set all the file's properties to Build Action: Content, Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy.

I now find that as I continue to develop and debug my code, the project build time has tripled to 30 seconds, making the debug experience painfully slow.

Presumably VS is processing or checking my image files during the build, even though they never change from one build to the next.

Is there any way I can reduce the build time in this situation?  Or is there some way to only include these files in the Release build and not the Debug build?

Comment: 5000 images? why not put them all on a api to access/download them on demand and remove them completely from the project? that way even your deployment file will be lot smaller. i'm pretty sure you do not use all 5000 images always. Just a suggestion

Comment: Yes. It used to be like that, but customer requirements changed. Actually, doing it this way has made the 'out of box' install much easier for the end user and removes the need for Internet connection so it can be supplied on USB stick.  It's just making my productivity nose dive.

Comment: There is no way for you to improve the build time as you have 5000 images in your package. But you can create two csproj with different settings in it's itemsgroup, then they will have different behavior when you choose to build it. And maybe with the msbuild command line you can create different build based on different condition. But I'm not so familar with msbuild. Anyway, two csproj looks suitable to you, will this helps?

Comment: Thanks Barry.  Yes, this may help and I will investigate.  However I think that this is more of a workaround, rather than a solution. So, because you say it is not possible to improve the build time in this situation then (if you agree) I will provide that as the answer to my question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that since posting this question I have wrapped the 5000 images into a single zip file and added that to the project as opposed to including the individual images.  This has resulted in reducing the build time to a more acceptable 8 secs.  So I get my productivity back !  But again this is another workaround.  It also means that after installation, and on first run, my app will have to unzip all the images to the LocalCache.  I realise this means duplicating disk space requirements but it seems to be working well and it all gets removed when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: @NigelP Yes please. I'm fine if you can post the answer because that would also be helpful for other communities. And thanks for the zip method, it looks also a good workaround for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  You will see from the comments above that it is not possible to reduce the build time in this situation.  But there are workarounds.  The zip method works for my situation, but may not be suitable generally.